# Javascript concatenate strings in array

Tags: javascript

Why does the following code not work? Can't figure it out.

```
            var string = "";
            for (var x; x < numbersArray.length; x++)
                string += numbersArray[x];
            alert(string);
```

`string` is empty at the end.

Comment: and what is the value of x at the starting ?

Comment: Did you try a debugger?

Comment: Also having variable names like "`string`" is considered bad practice.
Btw. you could also use `numbersArray.join("")`.

Answer (score 4):

`x` is `undefined`, which is not less than any number.
Therefore, your terminating condition is always false.

You probably want to start at `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
        var string = "";
        for (var x=0; x < numbersArray.length; x++)
            string += numbersArray[x];
        console.log(string);
```

Just make sure to initialize your x.